# Extract images from playwright page without requesting them again?

Tags: playwright, playwright-python

Let's say I've requested a page and it's fully loaded. Is it possible to save the images from the rendered/loaded page without sending another request for the image? This would be to avoid just collecting the individual image urls and hammering the server for each image again.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes here with the same problem.

Mine is a dynamic gif, so screenshot won't help much. I'm therefore intercepting them. I think here it will be better explained (https://thinkmobiles.com/posts/1798/).

Answer (score -1):

transfer this to python code.

```java
byte[] slideBg = page.locator("xpath=id(\"slideBgWrap\")").screenshot();
ByteArrayInputStream inStreambj = new ByteArrayInputStream(slideBg);
BufferedImage newImage = ImageIO.read(inStreambj);
ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", new File(url + "outputImage.jpg"));
```

Comment: Why not just provide Python code, as requested?

Comment: # Capture screenshot and convert to bytes : `slide_bg = page.locator('xpath=id("slideBgWrap")').screenshot()`